# Finding the minimum vertex cut of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.2.0**

Note: [`FindVertexCut`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindVertexCut.html) is new in 9.0.

---

It seems that Mathematica is not correctly finding the smallest set of vertices that will disconnect a graph. Here is an example:

```
 g = GraphData[{"Cycle", 5}]
 FindVertexCut[g];
 HighlightGraph[g, %]
```

results in vertices {3, 4} being removed. But removing two adjacent vertices of a cycle doesn't increase the number of components. If we remove 3 and 4, the graph is a tree and is still connected. This ends up happening with quite a few graphs, another example being the complete graph with 6 vertices. It only removes one vertex and doing so will obviously not disconnect the complete-6 graph. But it does work some of the time; e.g., with a 6-cycle, Mathematica removes two non-adjacent vertices.

Have I used FindVertexCut incorrectly? FindVertexCut with only a graph as its argument will result in "the smallest vertex cut of" my graph, and according to documentation, "A vertex cut of a graph g is a list of vertices whose deletion from g disconnects g." What's the problem here?

Comment: Seems like a bug ...  Works OK. for `n > 5`

Comment: Your conjecture appears to only be true for cycles. From what I can see, it *never* works on complete graphs (except for n = 2 or n = 3).

Comment: Yup. I was talking about cycles. You're right about complete graphs too.

Comment: Other users: Please confirm and tag as [tag:bugs] if you can repro

Answer (score 4):

This is bugged still in 10.1.

If you are forced to live with the buggy function, here's a brute-force method that should work correctly: it checks the size of a minimum cut, and tries all subsets of vertices of that size. Below, I assume that [`VertexConnectivity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexConnectivity.html) still works correctly.

```
g = CycleGraph[5, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

DisconnectedGraphQ[g_] := ! ConnectedGraphQ[g];
gh = VertexDelete[g, #] & /@ Subsets[VertexList[g], {VertexConnectivity[g]}];
cut = SelectFirst[gh, DisconnectedGraphQ, {}];
If[SameQ[{}, cut], VertexList[g], Complement[VertexList[g], VertexList[%]]]
```

Furthermore, the overloaded version `FindVertexCut[g,s,t]` is bugged. Consider the following:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 
    2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5, 1 <-> 8, 8 <-> 3}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
HighlightGraph[g, FindVertexCut[g, 5, 8]]
Length[ConnectedComponents[VertexDelete[g, FindVertexCut[g, 5, 8]]]]
```

Here, removing the claimed vertex cut `{1}` does not increase the number of components, and is not a vertex separator for vertices 5 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**  Now I recommend using [IGraph/M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97233/12) instead:

```
<<IGraphM`

IGMinSeparators[g]
(* {{2, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}} *)
```

---

An alternative workaround is using [igraph](http://igraph.org/) through my [IGraphR package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/using-igraph-from-mathematica.html).

[`minimum.size.separators`](http://igraph.org/r/doc/minimum.size.separators.html) gives *all* possible smallest vertex cuts.

Example:

```
<< IGraphR`

g = CycleGraph[5, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> Large]

vcs = IGraph["minimum.size.separators"][g]
(* {{2., 5.}, {2., 4.}, {3., 5.}, {1., 3.}, {1., 4.}} *)

HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ Round[vcs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @mrm You can't compare them in general.  There's of course an overhead to calling igraph, but igraph will sometimes use different algorithms which might make its performance significantly different.

Comment: Can you double check my claim for the st-version of `FindVertexCut` (see my update)? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @mrm Sorry, today is very busy here.  Remind me in a few days if I don't respond.