# Deleting vertices from a Graph and preserving structure

Tags: graphs-and-networks, list-manipulation

My goal is to remove vertices from graphs (and the edges from them) and then take `GraphComplement` to find out cut sets in graphs with sink and source such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116470/mincuts-from-graphs-to-find-permutations-that-break-the-system-into-disjoint-set). So

**How can I delete vertices from a graph and preserve the earlier structure?**

---

**Trials**

*Trial 1.* Failures in trying to remove vertices fom HararyGraph.

> The structure is not preserved for which `SetProperty` (?) and the repetitive assignment after each removal failing -- the table below removes the other vertex from new graph not from the one where one vertex was already removed.
>
> [image]

*Trial 2.* Failure in trying to remove vertices repetively from GridGraph, based on the case where [only one removal.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39840/2000)

> [image]

*Trial 3.* Question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120360/how-can-you-delete-a-list-of-vertices-from-a-gridgraph) to be more clear.

> ```
> SeedRandom[10801];
> dimension = 5;
> coDimension = 10;
> percProbability = 0.7;
> deleteMe = 
>  Pick[Table[i, {i, 1, 30}], Table[RandomReal[] > 0.5, {i, 30}]]
>
> g = GridGraph[{dimension, coDimension}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
>   ImagePadding -> 30]
> H = SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, #], 
>     VertexCoordinates -> Delete[GraphEmbedding[g], #]] & @@ deleteMe
>
> H = SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, deleteMe], 
>   VertexCoordinates -> Delete[GraphEmbedding[g], deleteMe]]
> ```
>
> [image]

**We are searching for perhaps relevant questions below.**

- [How to add new nodes to an existing graph with fixed (coordinates) nodes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31014/how-to-add-new-nodes-to-an-existing-graph-with-fixed-coordinates-nodes)
- [Keeping vertexcoordinates after adding a new vertex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31235/keeping-vertexcoordinates-after-adding-a-new-vertex)

*Ps. For the mincut goal, Alert! Alert about bug in at least 10.1 Mathematica in using Mathematica's own cut command: [Finding the minimum vertex cut of a graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63783/finding-the-minimum-vertex-cut-of-a-graph). Also notice that VertexConnectivity command bugging, [Is there something wrong with VertexConnectivity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22261/is-there-something-wrong-with-vertexconnectivity).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the GridGraph [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120360/how-can-you-delete-a-list-of-vertices-from-a-gridgraph). You need to fix the VertexCoordinates before deletions.

```
G = SetProperty[G, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[G]];
VertexDelete[G, deleteMe]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `vertexDeleteKeepEmbedding` which is a side effect of [Clickable graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116648/clickable-graph/117740#117740) answer:

```
gr = CompleteGraph[17, PlotRange -> 2]

FoldList[
    vertexDeleteKeepEmbedding, 
    gr, 
    RandomSample @ Most @ VertexList @ gr
] // ListAnimate
```

### [image]

```
vertexDeleteKeepEmbedding[graph_, vertex_] := Module[{
  coords, vertices = VertexList[graph]
  }
  , 
  coords = DeleteCases[vertices, vertex] /. Thread[
    vertices -> GraphEmbedding[graph]
  ];

  Graph[VertexDelete[graph, vertex], VertexCoordinates -> coords]
];
```

Comment: I added the Trial 3 with GridGraph: Can you demonstrate it with this method? `SeedRandom[10801];
dimension = 5;
coDimension = 10;
percProbability = 0.7;
deleteMe = 
 Pick[Table[i, {i, 1, 30}], Table[RandomReal[] > 0.5, {i, 30}]]

gr = GridGraph[{dimension, coDimension}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImagePadding -> 30]
H = SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, #], 
    VertexCoordinates -> Delete[GraphEmbedding[g], #]] & @@ deleteMe

FoldList[vertexDeleteKeepEmbedding, gr, RandomSample@Most@deleteMe@gr]`, something like this?