# Is there a bug in FindClique?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If `h` is a graph, [`FindClique[g, {n}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClique.html) should return a clique on *exactly* $n$ vertices if one exists in `h`.

Consider the following:

```
h = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 
   2 <-> 6, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
FindClique[h, {3}]
```

The output is `{}`. However, there is a clique on 3 vertices in `h`, like `{1,2,4}`. Is this indeed a bug, or am I overlooking something? Interestingly, `FindCycle[h, {3}, All]` *does* find all triangles of the graph, including `{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 4, 4 <-> 1}`. I would expect `FindClique[h, {3}, All]` to return exactly the same answer as `FindCycle[h, {3}, All]` in general.

I am running V10.0.0.0, by the way.

Comment: Confirmed in v9.0.1 and v10.0.2.  You really *should* upgrade to 10.0.2 BTW.  Please report this Wolfram support and let us know what they said.  Tagging as bug.

Comment: Or maybe I spoke too soon and it only find *maximal* cliques?  Let's wait until someone else chimes in.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, maybe. If it is so, the documentation is quite confusing...

Comment: Indeed, it is confusing.  But it appears that it finds maximal cliques only, the results agree with igraph when I test on many random graphs.  So not a bug in the functions ... but a bug in the documentation then.  I'll write an answer after breakfast

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug.  It appears that [`FindCliques`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindCliques.html) returns only *maximal cliques*, i.e. cliques (complete subgraphs) that are not a subset a larger clique.

In your example `{1,2,4}` is not maximal because it can be extended to `{1,2,4,5}`.

I would not call this a bug because the behaviour is consistent, and the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindCliques.html) does suggest that this is the case:

> `FindClique[g]` finds a **largest** clique in the graph g.
>
> ...
>
> A clique is a **maximal** set of vertices where the corresponding subgraph is a complete graph.

Personally I find this rather confusing because the standard definition of [*clique*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) that I am familiar with does not require it to be maximal.  It appears that by *cliques* Mathematica means *maximal cliques*.

**Update:**  As of 2015 May the documentation page of [`FindCliques`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindCliques.html) includes a Background section which explains precisely the terminology and what the function does.

---

**Update:**  Now I recommend using [IGraph/M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24544/how-can-i-conveniently-call-igraph-form-mathematica) instead of IGraphR.  The command is `IGCliques[g, Infinity]`.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95787/12) for more details.

Here's a quick test to show that Mathematica finds maximal cliques correctly, by comparing with [igraph](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/using-igraph-from-mathematica.html):

```
canonical = Sort[Sort /@ Round[#]] &

g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}];

canonical@FindClique[g, Infinity, All]

(* {{1, 6}, {1, 10}, {2, 6}, {2, 10}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 7, 8}, {3, 7, 9}, {4, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 5, 9}} *)

<<IGraphR`
canonical@IGraph["maximal.cliques"][g]

(* {{1, 6}, {1, 10}, {2, 6}, {2, 10}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 7, 8}, {3, 7, 9}, {4, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 5, 9}} *)

And @@ Table[
   With[{g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]}, 
     canonical@FindClique[g, Infinity, All] === canonical@IGraph["maximal.cliques"][g]],
   {100}]

(* True *)
```

---

Two workarounds for finding all cliques, not only maximal ones:

- First find the maximal ones, then take all `Subsets` of each clique.  This does not make it easy to find cliques *only up to size $k$* though.
- Use [igraph](http://igraph.org/) though [IGraphR](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/using-igraph-from-mathematica.html), like this: `IGraph["cliques"][h, 3, 3]` $\longrightarrow$ `{{1., 2., 3.}, {1., 2., 4.}, {1., 2., 5.}, {1., 3., 4.}, {1., 4., 5.}, {2., 3., 4.}, {2., 4., 5.}}`

Comment: Historical note: Luce and Perry (1949) required maximality and size >2 to be a clique http://aris.ss.uci.edu/~lin/50.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Mathematica finds only maximal cliques. It has more sense since any subset of clique is clique. So you can use `Subsets` to find *all* cliques of the size `k`

```
findAllCliques[g_, {k_}] := Union @@ (Subsets[#, {k}] & /@ FindClique[g, {k, ∞}])

findAllCliques[h, {3}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```