# How to count all cliques (not just maximal ones) in graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

How can I count the numbers of $r$-cliques in a graph? In other words, the number of triangles, the number of $K_4$, the number of $K_5$ etc. I have tried for example `FindClique[G,{4},All]`, which finds all "isolated" $K_4$s but does not find $K_4$s in a larger clique. So for example if $G = K_5$ then `FindClique[G,{4},All]` does not find the 4-cliques within `G` but `FindClique[G,{5},All]` does find the 5-clique. Is there a simple way of doing this with a Mathematica command or is it necessary to compute the number of smaller cliques from the number of larger cliques?

Comment: You can consider accepting Ralph's answer.  It performs very well.  In fact if the aim is to return all cliques (not just count them), I don't think it is at all technically possible to match it when using an external library, due to the performance limitations of Mathematica's C API.  (I'm quite disappointed about that.)

Answer (score 17):

Mathematica only finds *maximal cliques*, i.e. cliques (complete subgraphs) that are not part of a larger clique.

Computing the number of all cliques given the maximal ones is not trivial because some of the maximal cliques may be overlapping.

The simplest way to find *all* cliques is to use one of several packages that can do this.

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}];
```

#### [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM)

```
<<IGraphM`
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cliques = IGCliques[g, Infinity]

{{2}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, \
{14}, {17}, {18}, {20}, {22}, {26}, {24}, {25}, {28}, {29}, {30}, \
{27}, {31}, {32}, {33}, {15}, {16}, {19}, {21}, {23}, {34}, {2, 
  1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 14}, {2, 18}, {2, 20}, {2, 22}, {2, 
  31}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {1, 
  11}, {1, 12}, {1, 13}, {1, 14}, {1, 18}, {1, 20}, {1, 22}, {1, 
  32}, {3, 4}, {3, 8}, {3, 9}, {3, 10}, {3, 14}, {3, 28}, {3, 29}, {3,
   33}, {4, 8}, {4, 13}, {4, 14}, {5, 7}, {5, 11}, {6, 7}, {6, 
  11}, {6, 17}, {7, 17}, {9, 31}, {9, 33}, {9, 34}, {10, 34}, {14, 
  34}, {20, 34}, {26, 24}, {26, 25}, {26, 32}, {24, 28}, {24, 
  30}, {24, 33}, {24, 34}, {25, 28}, {25, 32}, {28, 34}, {29, 
  32}, {29, 34}, {30, 27}, {30, 33}, {30, 34}, {27, 34}, {31, 
  33}, {31, 34}, {32, 33}, {32, 34}, {33, 15}, {33, 16}, {33, 
  19}, {33, 21}, {33, 23}, {33, 34}, {15, 34}, {16, 34}, {19, 
  34}, {21, 34}, {23, 34}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 8}, {2, 1, 
  14}, {2, 1, 18}, {2, 1, 20}, {2, 1, 22}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 
  3, 14}, {2, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 14}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 8}, {1, 3, 9}, {1, 
  3, 14}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 4, 13}, {1, 4, 14}, {1, 5, 7}, {1, 5, 
  11}, {1, 6, 7}, {1, 6, 11}, {3, 4, 8}, {3, 4, 14}, {3, 9, 33}, {6, 
  7, 17}, {9, 31, 33}, {9, 31, 34}, {9, 33, 34}, {26, 25, 32}, {24, 
  28, 34}, {24, 30, 33}, {24, 30, 34}, {24, 33, 34}, {29, 32, 
  34}, {30, 27, 34}, {30, 33, 34}, {31, 33, 34}, {32, 33, 34}, {33, 
  15, 34}, {33, 16, 34}, {33, 19, 34}, {33, 21, 34}, {33, 23, 34}, {2,
   1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 3, 8}, {2, 1, 3, 14}, {2, 1, 4, 8}, {2, 1, 4, 
  14}, {2, 3, 4, 8}, {2, 3, 4, 14}, {1, 3, 4, 8}, {1, 3, 4, 14}, {9, 
  31, 33, 34}, {24, 30, 33, 34}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 8}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 14}}

 CountsBy[cliques, Length]
 (* <|1 -> 34, 2 -> 78, 3 -> 45, 4 -> 11, 5 -> 2|> *)
```

**Update:**  In IGraph/M 0.1.4 or later, we can directly count cliques, without listing them:

```
IGCliqueSizeCounts[g]
(* {34, 78, 45, 11, 2} *)
```

This release also significantly speeds up clique finding.

Since there is significant overhead in storing and transferring all the cliques back to Mathematica after computing them, `IGCliqueSizeCounts` can be many times faster than `IGCliques`.  If you only need counts, use `IGCliqueSizeCounts`.

#### [IGraphR](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphR)

This needs a bit more work as the output of R/igraph's `cliques` command doesn't easily transfer to Mathematica.

```
<<IGraphR`
REvaluate["cliqCounter <- function (g) { as.vector(table(sapply(cliques(g), length))) };"]

IGraph["cliqCounter"][g]
(* {34, 78, 45, 11, 2} *)
```

This gives you the number of cliques with sizes 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

#### [MmaCliquer](https://github.com/szhorvat/MmaCliquer)

This is a partial interface to [Cliquer](http://users.aalto.fi/~pat/cliquer.html) that I made for my own use.  Currently it can only *count* cliques of different sizes, but not return the vertices they contain.  This library is very fast for counting all cliques (but not so much for counting maximal ones).

Due to [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) issues you need to compile it yourself ...

```
<<Cliquer`

CliquerDistribution[g]
(* {34, 78, 45, 11, 2} *)
```

---

Finally, just for some fun with IGraph/M's isomorphism functions:

```
Table[IGVF2SubisomorphismCount[CompleteGraph[i], g]/IGBlissAutomorphismCount@CompleteGraph[i], {i, 5}]

(* {34, 78, 45, 11, 2} *)
```

Of course this is extremely inefficient :)

Comment: thank you - very helpful. Clive

Comment: @cliveelphick If you find any problems with these packages, please let me know!

Comment: I have posted a third, much simpler answer to this question, and would be grateful for a comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Szabolcs How does one compile/install `Cliquer`? Running `<<Cliquer` in Linux returns Get::noopen: Cannot open Cliquer`.

Comment: @Leo Just use IGraph/M instead. It also uses cliquer.

Comment: @Szabolcs There appears to be no option in IGCliqueSizeCounts to calculate the number of cliques of a specific size. For example, we would like to count the number of $K_4$, but it also counts the number of cliques of other size. The effect is a reduction in efficiency.

Answer (score 9):

1. Mathematica can return the set of all maximal cliques of a graph.
2. Any subset of clique vertices is also a clique.

So, this gives all cliques:

```
findAllCliques[g_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Map[Subsets, FindClique[g, Infinity, All]], 1]]
```

Try it:

```
n = RandomInteger[25];
m = RandomInteger[Binomial[n, 2]];
rgr = Graph[RandomGraph[{n, m}], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
allCliques = findAllCliques[rgr];
Print["n = ", n, "   m = ", m]
Print[Length@allCliques, " Cliques found"]
rgr
allCliques
Histogram@Map[Length, allCliques]
```

Comment: Hi Ralph!  Yes, this implementation is correct (but I would feel more comfortable if you used `DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ ...]` just to be sure ...). One potential problem is that if the cliques overlap in a certain way, there may be an extreme number of duplicates to be removed, which will slow it down and will have high memory requirements.  This is an example made to be difficult on purpose: `n = 12; g = CompleteGraph[2 n]; g = EdgeDelete[g, Table[i <-> i + n, {i, n}]];`.

Comment: In practice though it seems to work much better than I expected.  And the igraph function I recommended works much worse (much slower than your implementation).  There's something wrong with it, I'll take a look later.  Cliquer is still the winner *by far*.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you present the graph built by your line of code for testing findAllCliques. That took about 20 seconds on my MacBook Air.  Do you have timing for that using some other method?Question: in constructing your example, why did you generate CompleteGraph[24] and then delete some of its edges?

Comment: With the Cliquer library (last section in my answer) it takes 0.01 seconds.

Comment: My application requires the actual cliques rather than just how many there are.

Comment: I was attempting to create a graph with lots of overlapping cliques, and I didn't do it quite right, though this one seems to be difficult too.

Comment: Timing[findAllCliques[CompleteGraph[24]]]     45.706
Not too bad for that big a graph. I am only working with CompleteGraph[15].

Comment: My point is simply that your algorithm likely does more work than it needs to, due to having to filter duplicates.  Does that worsen its computational complexity?  Likely not as the clique problem is exponential anyway.  But it probably does add a bigger constant factor than necessary, which does matter.  While it's not apparent here, the Cliquer method does in fact internally list all cliques even though it does not return them to Mathematica.  "Just having to count" gives it no advantage.

Comment: I just needed it to work in concise code

Comment: What I am trying to ultimately get at is that this is probably not the best way to do it if you are implementing a clique finder from scratch.  That does not mean that it is not the fastest way to do it when working with the limited tools Mathematica offers, nor does it mean that it is not a practical method.  However, if we were doing this from scratch, program it in C, and call that from Mathematica, we wouldn't want to first find maximal cliques, take subgraphs and filter duplicates.

Comment: Certainly not! Fully agree on that.

Comment: I did not need any maximal cliques. That was Mathematica's idea!

Comment: But then I never wrote a clique finder from scratch.  Now you made me curious and I want to do it.

Comment: Also, thank you for this post.  It made me realize how slow igraph's clique finder is.  I will see if there is anything that can be done about it (and whether igraph's authors are open to doing that).

Comment: Ralph, I think in practice your solution is going to be the fastest way in Mathematica. Even though it has to do all that duplicate filtering, it's just not possible to return the same number of cliques fast enough from an external library using MathLink :-(

Answer (score 3):

A naive approach is to enumerate all ${n \choose r}$ subsets, and for each check whether the subset induces an $r$-clique. Obviously, this does not scale nicely when $r$ gets larger, nor when $n$ starts to get larger.

For special cases, i.e., small values of $r$ you can do better. A neat algebraic graph-theoretic way of computing the number of triangles is given by $\text{tr}(A^3)/6$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$. For counting 3-cliques, we can simply do

```
TriangleCount[g_] := Tr[MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3]]/6;
```