# Find independent vertex sets

Tags: graphs-and-networks, subset

I'm trying to find all independent vertex sets for a given graph. Note that they may not be maximal independent sets.

There is a function in *Mathematica* called `FindIndependentVertexSet`. But I noticed that it actually gives the maximum sets, not just the independent ones.

In the reference there is also `IndependentVertexSetQ` that test vertices. BUT it does not test for maximal sets.

The first question is if such behaviour is intended. I mean that one function works for Maximal sets and the other does not.

Another question is whether I have to manually find the independent sets or there is already a built in function.

Comment: You may be interested in the ["Background & Context" section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentVertexSet.html) of the documentation of `FindIndependentVertexSet`. Among other things, it states that: "Not-necessarily-maximal independent vertex sets cannot be found directly using `FindIndependentVertexSet` but can be simplistically enumerated by taking the union over the collection of all subsets of all maximal independent vertex sets."

Comment: Unfo, this is said only in online version. Or at least not in 10.3.|
Thanks for this note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a closely related question:

- [How to count all cliques (not just maximal ones) in graphs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/how-to-count-all-cliques-not-just-maximal-ones-in-graphs)

Based on Ralph Dratman's solution there, we can write (with slight modifications):

```
findAllCliques[g_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Join @@ Subsets /@ FindClique[g, Infinity, All]]

findAllIndependentVertexSets[g_] := findAllCliques@GraphComplement[g]
```

This will often be faster than the naive approach in the documentation that MarcoB mentioned.

---

Alternatively, the [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) package has a function to find *all* (not just maximal) independent vertex sets.

```
?IGIndependentVertexSets
```

> IGIndependentVertexSets[graphs] finds all independent vertex sets of graph. 
>   IGIndependentVertexSets[graphs, {min, max}] 
>   IGIndependentVertexSets[graphs, max] 
>   IGIndependentVertexSets[graphs, {n}]

You can restrict the search to independent vertex sets between sizes `min` and `max`, or up to `max`, or size precisely `n`.

```
?IGMaximalIndependentVertexSets
```

> IGMaximalIndependentVertexSets[graph] finds the maximal independent vertex sets of graph.

Comment: Disclosure: I'm the author of IGraph/M.

Comment: Thanks!
This works, should spend some time to understand HOW it works.

Will as well check your package.

However, should the in-built function work the way it does atm? As the name and description implies that it finds NOT the maximum set. Should this be reported?

Comment: Edit: NVM the previous question, as MarcoB noted about this being said in Backgroung section of reference.

Comment: @AndrewS. I see no point in reporting it.  It is clearly by design, and the behaviour is clearly documented.  They just made the function name a bit shorter by leaving out "maximal".  It's the same with `FindCliques`.

Comment: They as well added a note that Marco showed. But as I said in another comment, it's not in the 10.3 version (at least).

Thanks for help!

Comment: @AndrewS. That's strange, I can see it in the builtin documentation.  I have 10.3.1.  Do you have documentation updates disabled in preferences?

Comment: @AndrewS. Just to clarify: I was annoyed by this too when I discovered it first with `FindClique`.  I was looking to get *all* cliques. At that time they didn't even have the Background & Context section in the documentation.  You are right about the inconsistency with `IndependentVertexSetQ`.  And you can report it to support.  My point was just that it seems clear that these naming choices are deliberate, and I don't think reporting it will change anything.

Comment: Yeah, seems like updates are disabled on this PC.
I've stumbled upon a couple other inconsistencies like this in other parts as well. But I think you are right though. (Will try to report this nevertheless).
THanks again for help!