# Counting the number of triangles of a multigraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph with  some multiple edges. I tried to calculate the number of triangles in it, so I used the new function  **FindIsomorphicSubgraph**  of mathematica 13.  We get 64 triangles of the graph by FindIsomorphicSubgraph.

```
   g=AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
   1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}]
t = FindIsomorphicSubgraph[g, 
  Graph[{"a" \[UndirectedEdge] "b", "b" \[UndirectedEdge] "c", 
    "c" \[UndirectedEdge] "a"}], All]
t//Length
```

```
                             64
```

We use the IGraphM package as an aid.

`cliques = IGCliques[g, {3}] // Length`

```
                             64
```

[image]

The above function seems to compute the triangle by treating the  multiple edges as the same edge.

Let $A$ be a adjacent matrix  of the graph $g$ which has no loop edges but allows multiple edges.  we note that triangles with an ordering on the vertices are in 1-1 correspondence with directed, 3-step paths from each vertex to itself. So the number of triangles is equal to the trace of $A^3$ divided by $6$, since each triangle is counted twice (once in each direction) for each vertex in the triangle.

In fact, we seem to get more triangles if we use the following function to calculate.

```
TriangleCount[g_] := Tr[MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3]]/6;
TriangleCount[g]
                           72
```

FindIsomorphicSubgraph seems to ignore the  multiple edges. Although we can also count the lost triangles by following programming. (It's not that effective).

```
EdgeList /@ t; 
elist = EdgeList[g];
repeats[list_] := Select[Gather[list], Length[#] > 1 &][[1 ;;, 1]];
s = EdgeList /@ t // Flatten;
s1 = Count[s, #] & /@ repeats[elist];
Plus @@ s1
```

```
                             8
```

In other words, this function should state in the help documentation that it considers the  simple graphs to prevent misunderstanding.

Previously useful links:

- [How to count all cliques (not just maximal ones) in graphs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/how-to-count-all-cliques-not-just-maximal-ones-in-graphs)

Comment: I don't reproduce your results - when I run your code I find `Length[t]` returns 64.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry, in my context, my variable g may have been contaminated, and I'm now rerunging it to 64.

Comment: It is worth discussing, then, whether  the multiple edges should be regarded as one.

Comment: @licheng Since no answers have been submitted yet, Please edit the question to remove the first issue that turned out to be erroneous and focus on your second question. You will also want to edit the title accordingly.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for reminding, I will change this post.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following works.  It finds 64 triangles in your multigraph.

```
Print[Framed[<< "IGraphM`", Background -> Yellow]];
g = AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
      1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 
     1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
     0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
     0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
     1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}];
Print[Length[IGTriangles[g]]];
```

Comment: There are 8 triangles involved here that are ignored.