# Manipulatable Geometry from an Image

Tags: manipulate, image-processing, image, animation

Is there any way, I can take an existing internet image and have *Mathematica* read it in, so it can be manipulated using the `Manipulate` function?

The image I would like to use -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract#/media/File:8-cell.gif

Failing that, as it's a fairly standard 4D shape, can this be recreated using the in built geometrical objects

Edit: Doesn't have to be using the `Manipulate` function - that was more my best guess.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/how-to-create-this-four-dimensional-cube-animation

Comment: Remarkably similiar project! Not sure how i missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get the sequence list of individual frames:

```
myseq = Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/8-cell.gif"]
```

then to show them:

```
ListAnimate[myseq]
```

and "manipulate" the scroll bar.  Or if you must use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[myseq[[j]]],
 {j, 1, Length[myseq], 1}]
```

Note that this is a sequence of flat images, so you cannot manipulate the viewpoint, lighting, etc.  For that you'll have to write code to generate the 3D form.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Quick questions: 1) What is the 1 for in the {j, 1, Length...}? 2) How do i upvote your answer, doesn't seem to work for me? 3) If I did want to write the code for the 3D form, how would i start going about that?

Comment: @Tinsiles:  the syntax of a variable in `Manipulate` of `{j, 1, 5}` (say) would mean that you could slide to any real value in that range, e.g., 2.94.  That makes no sense for a discrete, indexed set of images.  If the iterator is `{j, 1, 5, 1}` it means that `j` can go between $1$ and $5$ *in steps of 1*.  (Perhaps your reputation is too low to up-vote.  When you gain more reputation points, return and up-vote.  When you get even more (100?) you can click on the check mark to "accept" my answer.)