# Rotate 120-Cell Animation

Tags: graphics, geometry, animation, projection

I have seen some code (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9593) to create an animation of a hypercube rotating, but I'm really struggling to understand how it works. I find it quite complicated. Suppose I would like to create a very similar animation, but rather than a hypercube, using a "hyperdodecahedon" (AKA 120-cell) instead? Does the code need to be completely rewritten in order to achieve that, or can it be done with just a few minor changes? How would you create that animation for a 120-cell?

Perhaps something like this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/120-cell.gif

Comment: "can it be done with just a few minor changes?" - first, you'd need a representation of the 120-cell (vertices, edges, etc.). Do you already have one?

Comment: `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords4D.A.P, primitives]]`, where `A` is the appropriate `RotationMatrix[]`, and `P` is a projection matrix from 4D to 3D (maybe just the first three coordinates). Making it artistic requires some knowledge of good choices for `A` and `P` or a lot of experimentation.  A perspective projection might be better than an orthogonal one, but each would give a different look.

Comment: An old Mathematica computation is described in [Sullivan 1990](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/Papers/dodecaplex/new.pdf)