# About extension fibonacci

Tags: programming

I have been trying to solve [this](http://astar.baidu.com/index.php?r=home/detail&id=2) problem, it worked slow.
I know there is a efficiently way. How do I get it?

The following is my code:

```
f[{a_, b_, nth_}] := Nest[#~Join~IntegerDigits@Tr[#[[-2 ;;]]] &, {a, b}, nth - 2][[nth]];

f /@ {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 8}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 5, 10^5 - 1}, {1, 7, 10^5}}
```

## additional

1. Integer a,b in range 0 to 9,combine them to a string ab
2. Make the last and penultimate number plus then appendto ab

repeat 2.,the string can any infinitely expanding.
Now we need know what is the nth number.

For example:

1,1 ==> 11235813471123...

1,2 ==> 12358134711235...

1,5 ==> 156112358134711...

f(1,1,2)=1

f(1,1,8)=3

f(1,4,8)=9

**update**

I have got a way, but I feel it's not neat.

```
f[{a_, b_, n_}] :=
  Module[{li, pos, left, repeat},
   li = NestWhile[#~Join~IntegerDigits@Tr[#[[-2 ;;]]] &, {a, b}, 
     FreeQ[Partition[#[[;; -2]], 2, 1], #[[-2 ;;]]] &];

   pos = Position[Partition[li, 2, 1], li[[-2 ;;]], 1, 1][[1, 1]];
   {left, repeat} = {#[[;; pos - 1]], #[[pos ;; -3]]} &@li;
   If[n <= Length[left], left[[n]], 
    repeat[[Mod[n - Length[left], Length[repeat], 1]]]]
   ];

f /@ {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 8}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 5, 10^8 - 1}, {1, 7, 10^8}}
```

Comment: Coluld you explain your problem in english, not in chinese ?

Comment: My English is bad, I am afraid that my expression is not clear.

Comment: Can you explain your problem via mathematics?

Comment: Ok, Let me try.

Comment: You can certainly increase the computation time by not actually calculating every step and instead using some clever algorithm. [I made a graph of the transitions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dQVxL.png)

Comment: Do I understand correctly? the sequence of digits involved is *not* quite what you'd get by generalizing the classic Fibonacci sequence to the case of an arbitrary pair of initial integers. Rather, after the two initial values, you sum the preceding two digits in the decimal integer formed by juxtaposing the preceding numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not full solution, just a non-bruteforce way to do it.

Noting that there are 3 distinct cycles you can end up in, namely:

```
cycles={
  {{0,0}},
  {{1,4},{4,5},{5,9}},
  {{1,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,5},{5,8},{1,3},{3,4},{4,7}}
};
distance=Map[If[Total[#]>=10,2,1]&,cycles,{2}];
(* {{1},{1,1,2},{1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2}} *)
```

Say you arrive at:
`...166713`
Here your last two digits `{1,3}` are part of the third cycle, in which every tenth digit is the same, so the digit k-steps further in the sequence will be the same as 10*n + k further. So if you have k-steps remaining you only need to calculate the next `Mod[k,10]`

I discovered the cycles by looking at [the graph of the transitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQVxL.png) and used some inefficient code to extract the cycles

```
next[a_,b_]:=Module[{sum=a+b},
  If[sum >= 10,
    QuotientRemainder[sum,10],
    {b,sum}]
];
vertices=Tuples[Range[0,9],2]; (* all {i,j} for i,j between 0 and 9 *)

cycles = Module[{cycles = {}, n, s, cycle},
   Scan[(
      n = #;
      cycle = {n};
      n = next @@ n;

      (* Keep adding next {a,b} pair to the cycle until we have seen it before *)
      While[FreeQ[cycle, n],
       AppendTo[cycle, n];
       n = next @@ n
       ];
      (* Where was it first seen? *)    
      s = Position[cycle, n][[1, 1]];
      (* Add the detected cycle to our list of all cycles*)
      AppendTo[cycles, cycle[[s ;; -1]]]
      ) &
    , vertices];
   (* Remove duplicate cycles*)
   Union[Map[RotateLeft[#, First@Ordering[#] - 1] &, cycles]]
   ];
```

Comment: DL posted a cycle detection algorithm here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2840/193. I think it's already implemented natively in V9

Comment: For the purpose of identifying the $n$th *digit* in these "Fibonacci strings"--rather than just the $n$th step of their generation--it would be more convenient to represent the cycles slightly differently; namely, as $(14,45,59,91)$ and $(11,12,23,35,58,81,13,34,47,71)$.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>not so much an answer but an observation.</strike>

Your sequence always converges to either the pattern: $\dots, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, \dots$  or $\dots, 1,4,5,9, \dots $ and periodically repeats itself to infinity. You can test that if you evaluate:

```
g[i_, j_] := Block[{f, MyQuotRem},
             MyQuotRem[a_] := If[a < 10, {a}, a~QuotientRemainder~10];
             f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1]~Join~MyQuotRem[(Take[f[n - 1], -2] /. List -> Plus)];
             f[0] = {i, j};
             f[100]~MatchQ~{__, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, __}|| f[100]~MatchQ~{__, 1, 4, 5, 9, __}]
```

like so

```
Table[g[i,j], {i, 1, 9}, {j, 0, 9}]
```

(I used 100 iterations arbitrarily, the convergence happens much earlier). So you don't need to calculate future terms at all - you just need to use some sort of modular division to characterise the terms in your sequence.

**-------EDIT-------**

For example, you can modify the code to scan for the first instance of `{__,4,7,__}` and `{__,5,9,__}` (below, that's the `While` loop). After that, you generate a repeating sequence. I can't think of a nicer way than manually assigning this (having amended a mistake @whuber noticed):

```
Clear@g;

g[i_Integer, j_Integer, l_Integer] := Block[{f, MyQuotRem, conv1, conv2, p}, 
      MyQuotRem[a_] := If[a < 10, {a}, a~QuotientRemainder~10];
      f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1]~Join~MyQuotRem[(Take[f[n - 1], -2] /. List ->Plus)];
      f[0] = {i, j};
      conv1 = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7};
      conv2 = {1, 4, 5, 9};
      k = 1; While[!((f[k]~MatchQ~{__, 4, 7, __}) || f[k]~MatchQ~{__, 5, 9, __}), p[i, j] = f[k]; k++];
      If[l <= Length@p[i, j], g[i, j, l] = p[i, j][[l]],
           If[Last@p[i, j] == 7,
           g[i, j, l] = conv1[[Mod[l - Length@p[i, j], Length@conv1, 1]]],
           g[i, j, l] = conv2[[Mod[l - Length@p[i, j], Length@conv2, 1]]]]]]
```

Now, say, `g[1,7,234^567]` calculates your $ 234^{567}$-th term starting from $ \{1, 7\}. $ (which is a 3)

<strike>given `{1,2}` as an initial condition, any `n`th term is given by</strike>

```
{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7}[[Mod[10 + n, 9]]]
```

so you need only worry about the first few terms until the convergence occurs. You can modify my code to scan for the first instance of `{1,1}` or `{1,4}` and calculate future terms accordingly.

Comment: The final expression needs some modifications to be correct: it must compute modulo $10$ (the length of the cycle) rather than modulo $9$ and it must offset the result by $1$, because *MMA* will complain when you try to index that list with a zero.

Comment: @whuber thanks - I wrote this after a long day and for some stupid reason added 1 instead of offsetting by 1. Amended the whole thing now.