# Is a bug about the FindFundamentalCycles?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

My graph is

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 
   7 <-> 0, 0 <-> 1, 6 <-> 8, 8 <-> 3, 3 <-> 9, 9 <-> 15, 15 <-> 14, 
   14 <-> 13, 13 <-> 2, 4 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, 11 <-> 10, 10 <-> 9}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[g, #, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ 
 FindFundamentalCycles[g]
```

[image]

But actually this four cycle is expected.How can I get it?

[image]

This a bug of `FindFundamentalCycles` or I have a bad comprehension about it?

---

**Updat1:**

I find [a post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77955/21532) same to me topic.But this solution will give a unexpected result.

---

**Update2:**
I realize this is a unanswerable.Let's see a example:

We get `g1`:

```
g1 = PlanarGraph[{2, 1, 3, 5, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 5, 5 <-> 4, 4 <-> 1,
    1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

So as this topic.The cycle 1-2-5-3-1 and 1-4-5-3-1 is expected.And let change a layout:

```
g2 = PlanarGraph[{4, 1, 2, 5, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 5, 5 <-> 4, 4 <-> 1,
    1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

In this layout,the cycle 1-2-5-4-1 and 1-3-5-2-1 is expected.**Note the cylce 1-4-5-3-1 in this graph**,is a Unexpected in this layout.But I just change the layout..

Since so,let we try to understand what is a fundamental cycles(cycle basis).The @Martin Büttner have a mention about this.Yeah.I think so now.This is a manual operation for the fundamental cycles by the `FindSpanningTree`.

```
tree = FindSpanningTree[g];
edge = EdgeList@GraphDifference[g, tree];
HighlightGraph[g, FindCycle[EdgeAdd[tree, #]], 
   GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ edge
```

[image]

We can see,this result is same to we use `FindFundamentalCycles[]` and this rule apply to other graph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what you're seeing is a valid solution. Fundamental cycles are defined with respect to a spanning tree. In fact, the documentation says about `FindFundamentalCycles`:

> `FindFundamentalCycles` uses the result of `FindSpanningTree` as the default spanning tree.

A fundamental cycle is then defined as a cycle that uses one edge *not* in the tree and the corresponding unique path *through* the tree. Let's look at the spanning tree:

```
HighlightGraph[g, FindSpanningTree@g, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

We can see that your output is consistent with this spanning tree. The fundamental cycles correspond to the missing edges, `{10, 11}`, `{14, 15}`, `{6, 8}` and `{5, 6}`, respectively.

You can also convince yourself that these fundamental cycles do indeed form a valid cycle basis: by taking the symmetric difference between cycles 3 and 4, you'll obtain the cycle you're looking for.

Of course this means that the set of fundamental cycles is not unique. Start from a different spanning tree, and you'll get different cycles. I suppose what you're looking for is a set of fundamental cycles with minimal overall length (or weight). Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that `FindFundamentalCycles` comes with any options to look for such a solution specifically (or to use a different spanning tree as the basis). If I find some time later, I'll try to code up a solution for this, but at least I hope I've convinced you that this behaviour is not a bug.

In the meantime [have a look at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis#Polynomial_time_algorithms) which describes a polynomial-time algorithm to find a minimal cycle basis. However, it seems that this isn't necessarily a fundamental cycle basis. According to the subsequent section finding a minimum-weight fundamental cycle basis is actually NP-hard. I guess which route you're taking here depends on what your actual goal is.

Comment: Perhaps one could write a custom function that takes the graph and the spanning tree and gives the corresponding fundamental cycles (doesn't seem too messy). Then the options of `FindSpanningTree` could be used to tweak the results.

Comment: I have updated it and thanks for your help.

Comment: @KellenMyers I have done what you mean.