# Checking if a Graph forms a Mesh

Tags: graphs-and-networks, regions, computational-geometry, mesh, lattices

Given a random graph, I want to define a function `MeshGraphQ` that tests if the graph is a lattice (or mesh) graph. Here, I don't need the tiling to be regular. Therefore, I believe it is enough to check the following

1. If any two edges intersect.
2. If some part of the graph does not form a polygon.
3. If the graph is disconnected.

If any of these points are true, return `False`. Return `True` otherwise.

For example, I want `MeshGraphQ` to return `True` for the graphs

[image]

and `False` for the graphs

[image]

Just to give a bit of context, my goal is to slightly improve the `graphToMesh` function defined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112162/64001), in order to account for the cases where the graph does not define a lattice. I presume Mathematica already has some tools to help me do this, but I'm not used to working with graphs much, so any ideas/hints are appreciated.

Comment: Please check the update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. To verify that the graph can be drawn in the plane without edge crossings, use `PlanarGraphQ`. But note that you could have a mesh on a toroidal surface and that is not planar. This check is not really necessary.
2. To verify that all faces of the graph form a polygon, check that it is biconnected: `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[graph, 2]`
3. To check that it is connected, use `ConnectedGraphQ`

Comment: Regarding 1, it doesn't seem to work (doesn't work for the first example of those that should yield `False`). I'm only interested in 2D lattices. Any alternatives? Does the `KVertexConnectedGraphQ` function solve this?

Comment: @samwolfe Are you saying that you have a non-planar graph for which `PlanarGraphQ` returns `True`? That *could* be a bug, but it's much more likely that you are mistaken about it being non-planar. You can edit an example into the question. BTW "If any two edges intersect" makes no sense for *graphs*, as graphs are not geometrical objects. If you are talking about a specific drawing of a graph, that's an entirely different thing.