# Looking for two vertex-disjoint (chordless) cycles with length 10

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Two cycles in a graph are vertex-disjoint if they have no common vertex.   I am looking for two vertex disjoint (chordless) cycles with length 10.

```
g = Graph[{0 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 7, 7 <-> 6, 6 <-> 8, 2 <-> 3, 
   3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 10, 10 <-> 11, 11 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 13, 
   13 <-> 15, 0 <-> 12, 6 <-> 13, 15 <-> 14, 14 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 
   16 <-> 15, 11 <-> 16, 8 <-> 0, 3 <-> 9, 10 <-> 5, 7 <-> 19, 
   19 <-> 18, 16 <-> 17, 17 <-> 8, 5 <-> 18, 14 <-> 19, 17 <-> 18}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

```
c10 = FindCycle[g, {10}, All]; (* find all cycles with length 10.*)
```

```
convelist[cycle_] := Union[Flatten[Map[List @@ # &, cycle]]] (* convert cycle to vertex lists*)
noIntersectionQ[list1_, list2_] := Intersection[list1, list2] == {};(* test if vertex lists of two cycles are disjoint *)
(*main function*)
finddisjointcycles[listOfLists_] := 
  Module[{n = Length[listOfLists], i, j}, 
   For[i = 1, i <= n - 1, i++, 
    For[j = i + 1, j <= n, j++, 
     If[noIntersectionQ[listOfLists[[i]], listOfLists[[j]]], 
      Return[{i, j, listOfLists[[i]], listOfLists[[j]]}]]]];
   Return[None]];
```

```
finddisjointcycles[listcycle]
```

{1, 111, {3, 4, 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}, {0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8,
10, 11, 12}}

```
HighlightGraph[g, {c10[[1]], c10[[111]]}]
```

[image]

I feel like my code is too cumbersome. I hope it can be **simplified**.

The **second objective** is to find two vertex-disjoint chordless cycles with length 10. Both of the cycles found above are not chordless cycle.

> A **chord** of a graph cycle $C$ is an edge not in the edge set of $C$ whose endpoints lie in the vertex set $C$.

For example, in the following graph, the edge $3-4$ is a chord of the cycle $1-2-3-4-1$.

[image]

> A **chordless cycle** of a graph $G$ is a graph cycle in $G$ that has no cycle chord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Streamlining the code

In `convelist`,

- `Map[List@@#&,cycle]` is succinctly written as `List@@@cycle`.
- You can map on the second level (i.e. over the vertex indices instead of the UndirectedEdges): for instance, `Union@Reap[Map[Sow,cycle,{2}]][[2,1]]`.
- Since each edge in a cycle is ordered consistently, you can just use Span to take the first vertex in each edge: `cycle[[;;,;;,1]]`

Your `noIntersectionQ` can be replaced with `DisjointQ`.

In `finddisjointcycles`,

- If you forgo For loops, declaring `i`, `j` and `n` becomes unnecessary.  Keeping in mind [Is there a Break[] equivalent for short-circuiting in Table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/is-there-a-break-equivalent-for-short-circuiting-in-table), you could use `Table`:

  ```
  Table[
    If[DisjointQ@@listOfLists[[{i,j}]], Return[{i,j},Table]],
  {i,Length@listOfLists},{j,i-1}]
  ```

While your functions are very useful for learning the internals of Mathematica, I'd say they're simple enough to not warrant definition.  So I'd write something like

```
finddisjointcycle[g_Graph]:=
  Table[ If[DisjointQ@@#[[{i,j}]],Return[{i,j},Table]],
  {i,Length@#},{j,i-1}]& @FindCycle[g,{10},All][[;;,;;,1]]
```

If you want to find all such cycles, you can exploit `SequencePosition`:

```
finddisjointcycles[g_Graph] := SequencePosition[
   FindCycle[g,{10},All][[;;,;;,1]],
{x_,___,y_}/;DisjointQ[x,y]:>{x,y},Overlaps->True]
```

with the added benefit that you can simply include an extra `,1` parameter to limit it to one instance.

## Chordless

You could somehow filter the result of `FindCycle` to only deal with chordless ones.  Alternatively, I believe `FindFundamentalCycles` would return all chordless cycles, so you can filter its result for 10 long single face cycles.

Comment: Thanks! I just see this link for chordless graphs: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45112/finding-all-chordless-simple-cycles-in-a-graph