# How to find a cycle with a property in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let's have a graph with this edge list:

```
edgelist = 
{s -> 1, s -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 3 -> t, 4 -> 3, 4 -> t};
```

I want to know how to find all cycles with `length>3` that must contain `s` or `t` or *both*

Comment: Use any of the answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2719) to find cycles, and then select only the cycles that satisfy your conditions.

Comment: I tried to do it like this, and i get the same cycle twice at the end.
it's a cycle that starts with s and contains t
and the other starts with t and contains s. It's the same, and i don't want this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

If those edges are directed, then you haven't got any cycles involving `s` or `t`. To specify undirected edges use `\[UndirectedEdge]`, which shows up on SE as `<->`.

```
edgeList = {s <-> 1, s <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 1, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> t, 4 <-> 3, 4 <-> t};
G = Graph[edgeList, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

tCycle = FindCycle[{G, t}, {4, Infinity}, All];
sCycle = FindCycle[{G, s}, {4, Infinity}, All];
Union[tCycle, sCycle]
```

**Update**

Nasi points out that the union contains the same edge list twice. Sorting each at levels 1 and 2 before taking the union will get rid of the duplicates.

```
tCycle = Map[Sort, tCycle, 2]
sCycle = Map[Sort, sCycle, 2]
Union[tCycle, sCycle]
```

Perhaps there is a clever `SameTest` option for `Union` that allows more flexibility.

Comment: I know this method, but if we use this first we get a cycle that contains both s and t and then we get another cycle that contains both and the union shows them both with a different starting vertex